# upgrading Biztalk 2004 to Biztalk 2006 R2

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have a client running a 1/2 dozen or so orchestrations running on Biztalk 2004 (that I wrote) that they use to exchange cXML documents (mostly too send orders) with their suppliers. It has a ASP.NET 1.1 front end. It uses the SQL adapter to store the parsed cXML. I gets & sends the documents via HTTPS.

My question: Is the upgrade to Biztalk 2006 R2 as straight forward as MS says? Any advice or things I should watch out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finished a similar upgrade last year with little effort other than importing the projects into Visual Studio 2005.  The upgrades were without issue.  The biggest problem we had was with the various deployment scripts we used.  There was a bit of rewriting to work with some of the new features of 2006.  We also had to adjust to the multiple-host model for our apps.  But all in all, no problems - just more features and API changes on deployment.

Best of luck.

Comment: I deploy everything by hand and I have only one host, so it sounds like I'm all set. Thanks!

Comment: You get the option more easily to use multiple hosts in 2006.  I'd look into it for performance reasons and isolation reasons.  By using seperate hosts, you can redeploy BizTalk applications (new concept in 2006) without interfering with other applications.

Answer (score 1):

At some point you will want to review the recommended tuning parameters for BizTalk 2006 R2 - I've prepared a list that may be helpful of the relevant resource links

http://intltechventures.blogspot.com/2008/11/2008-11-01-saturday-biztalk-2006-r2.html